# Fatal Error uncaught error call to a member function fetch_assoc()on null in

Tags: php

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVQfF.png)   I just dont get where I am wrong. Can somebody help me with this? I feel stupid right now

```
 function total_price() {
        $total = 0;
        global $con;
        $ip = getIp();
        $select_price = $con->query("SELECT * from shoppingcart WHERE IP_address='$ip'");
        while($row = $select_price->fetch_assoc()) {
            $pro_id = $row['Product_id'];
            $quan = $row['Quantity'];
            $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_id='$pro_id'");
            while($row2 = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $row2['product_price'] *= $quan;
                $productprice = array($row2['product_price']);
                $values = array_sum($productprice);
                $total += $values;
            }
        }
        echo "₱: ".$total;
    }
```

Comment: Which of those two fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think there your $con->query(...) fails and so you `$select_price` is `FALSE` and not an object with some member functions.

Check Out the documentation of $mysqli::query

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

If you want to get the sql error print the Result of `$con->error`.

For example:

```
     $select_price = $con->query("SELECT * from shoppingcart WHERE IP_address='$ip'");
    if($select_price == FALSE) {
        echo "SQL-Error:".$con->error
        exit;
    }
            while($row = $select_price->fetch_assoc()) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if fetch_assoc fails there is a problem with your result set.

Problem ist that:

$query

or

$select_price

is not a valid Result-Set.

Reason could be that the Querys to the database fails.

you can check this by doing:

print_r($select_price);
print_r($query);

Should Output: Ressource ID #XX -> if not, check your Query direct agains SQL.

hope this helps